# Pagination issue with Layered navigation on custom page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, pagination

I had followed the steps from the link https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-layered-navigation-on-custom-page-in-magento-2 to create custom page with layered navigation.

Layered Navigation is working fine but the pagination is not showing/working properly.

Mynamespace/CustomModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noMynamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Context" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProviderInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateKeyInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\CollectionFilterInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price" type="Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price" />
</config>
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/view/frontend/layout/layerednavigation_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noMynamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-brand"/>
    <attribute name="class" value="page-with-filter"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="layerednavigation_index_index" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
            <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
            </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.stockalert1" as="stock_alert1" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/stockalert.phtml"></block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" as="navigation" before="-" template="Mynamespace_CustomModule::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/state.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Model/Layer.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    protected $request;
    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $brandName = urldecode($this->request->getParam('brand_name'));

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $finalOptions = array();
        foreach ($options as $option){
            if($option['value']!= ''){
                $index = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($option['label']));
                $finalOptions[$index] =$option['value'];
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->_productCollections['brand_collection'])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections['brand_collection'];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addWebsiteFilter();
            $collection->addStoreFilter();

            if(isset($finalOptions[$brandName])) {
                $collection ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $finalOptions[$brandName]);
            } else {
                //TODO: handle 404 from controller if no brandname
                $collection ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', '0000000');
            }

            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);

            //$collection->getSize();

            $this->_productCollections['brand_collection'] = $collection;
        }
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Model/Layer/Resolver.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer;

class Resolver extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer $layer,
        array $layersPool
    ) {
        $this->layer = $layer;
        parent::__construct($objectManager, $layersPool);
    }

    public function create($layerType)
    {

    }
}
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Model/ResourceModel/Layer/Filter/Price.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\DimensionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\IndexScopeResolverInterface;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Layer\Filter\Price
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $connectionName = null,
        IndexScopeResolverInterface $priceTableResolver = null,
        Context $httpContext = null,
        DimensionFactory $dimensionFactory = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $eventManager, $layerResolver, $session, $storeManager, $connectionName, $priceTableResolver, $httpContext, $dimensionFactory);
    }
}
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Block/Navigation.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block;

class Navigation extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $filterList,
            $visibilityFlag);
    }
}
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Block/Navigation/State.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block\Navigation;

class State extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $data);
    }
}
```

Mynamespace/CustomModule/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\CustomModule\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Mynamespace\CustomModule\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }
}
```